# export to pdf gridview is empty .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

while i try to export a gridview to pdf, the only thing i get is an empty table. here is the code i used:

```
protected void ExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End(); 
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //required to avoid the runtime error "  
    //Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." 

}
```

the gridview is binded like this:

```
  string from = Request.QueryString["FromDate"];
        string to = Request.QueryString["ToDate"];

        TextBox1.Text = from;
        TextBox2.Text = to;


        string strCon = System.Web
          .Configuration
          .WebConfigurationManager
          .ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString;

        String userSearchCommand = "my query is inserted here";

        SqlDataSource dataSource = new SqlDataSource(strCon, userSearchCommand);
        dataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        dataSource.ID = "all1";
        GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

The point is that i canot bind the gridview when tryiing to export it.
can anybody help me pls?

Comment: What is DataSource for GridView1 in your case? I mean it can be empty.

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko the DataSource is the query which data fills the gridview.

Comment: But are you sure that GridView1 is fulled with data? Make GridView1.RenderControl(hw); var test = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString(); and check what is in "test" variable.

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko the datasource is put in code behind and not in gridview declaration. practically, in the application it has data, but in the PDF document i only get empty rows.

Comment: Ok, and are Document and HTMLWorker from iTextsharp or from some other library?

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko from iTextsharp

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko the problem as far as i can see is all in gridview databinding. since it is populated dynamically, i probably do not know how to bind it correctly

Comment: Could you show how do you bind this DataGrid?

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko i edited the code above